# find line do not have two consecutive zeros

Tags: linux, grep

I'm trying to find line that does not have two consecutive zeroes and alphabet.

so I tried:

```
grep -v "00|[a-z]" filename
```

but didn't work....

how can I solve this?

Comment: grep by default does not recognize EREs. escape that `|` and it'll work, or specify -E option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split to two separate conditions

```
grep -v -e '00' -e '[a-z]'
```

Comment: Repeating `-e` is match any rather than match all.

Comment: @alaniwi but OP didn't provide sample lines and expected output.. `and` is used in description but `|` in the code.. it could go either way or OP wanted something else, who knows

Comment: @Sundeep Fair point. OP said that code didn't work so I assumed that they must mean they wanted AND, as per the description. Hence my perl solution. Similarly also Ed Morton's subsequent awk solution. Though now I see that OP's code doesn't implement OR either, for reasons stated in Oguz Ismail's comment.

Comment: I thought the most likely was they wanted only numbers but not 00.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'print unless /00/ && /[a-z]/' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '!(/00/ && /[a-z]/)' filename
```